# Touch action not working in java client 2.1.0 for ios automation

Tags: java, ios

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("testElement"));
Point point = element.getLocation();
Dimension size = element.getSize();

int elementCenterX = point.getX() + Math.round(size.getWidth() / 2);
int elementCenterY = point.getY() + Math.round(size.getHeight() / 2);

String originalContext = driver.getContext();
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
driver.tap(1, elementCenterX , elementCenterY , 1000);
driver.context(originalContext );
```

I tried this not working in osx 10.10,xcode 6.1 and appium 1.3.4. java_client 2.1
Any suggestion for how to touch action in real device using appium driver.